# Как в python unittest запустить один набор тестов несколько раз

Tags: python, python-3.x, юнит-тесты, python-unittest

Хочется запускать тесты на нескольких сборках программы за один запуск. Пример кода, очищенный от лишнего:

```
import unittest

suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover("./tests")
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()

for build in [build1, build2]:
    get_the_build(build)
    runner.run(suite)
```

На первой сборке тесты проходят, но на второй итерации runner падает с ошибкой:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Path/to/my/folder/run_tests.py", line 9, in <module>
    runner.run(suite)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\runner.py", line 176, in run
    test(result)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Что происходит? Какие результаты он пытается вызвать и почему не получается? Как правильно решить такую задачу?

Comment: Может что-то вроде [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) попробовать применить?

Comment: А как это поможет? Разделить запуски разных билдов по разным виртуальным средам? Так можно просто несколько раз запустить тесты подкладывая нужный билд. Вопрос был - как это сделать автоматически?Ну или хотя бы, что происходит с TextTestRunner при запуске второй раз.

Comment: Можно в [коде TestRunner](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/unittest/runner.py#L29) посмотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кратко переведу для соотечественников итог расследования, начатого парнем с Кубы, который проделал большую работу по исследованию исходного кода unittest. [Оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278700/how-to-run-the-same-testsuite-multiple-times-unittest-texttestrunner)

Когда тесты запускаются, они перезаписываются на None. У меня была идея, что тесты удаляются из сьюта, но если до и после запуска добавить `suite.countTestCases()` они вернут одинаковые числа, что и ввело меня в заблуждение. Правильно: добавить `print(suite)` - он покажет, что после запуска тестов в suite хранится `None`. Предложенный флаг не сработал, поэтому работающее решение в каждой итерации собирать тесты заново:

```
import unittest

runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()

for build in [build1, build2]:
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover("./tests")
    get_the_build(build)
    runner.run(suite)
```